# Serialize object and store it as string in cookie

Tags: java, spring

I  am java spring mvc  developer I have an object and i want to store it in cookie but I dont know how to serialize the object to save it 
someone can help me? or  can suggest other idea to store object in cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Size of a cookie could be max 4Mb. This might not be veryusefull for storing objects. You should consider using HTML5 storage as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can story the object in any String format you want in the cookie.

Build a custom `toString()` and constructor from `String` for your object. Write to the cookie `ojectToSave.toString()` and when reading from the cookie construct `objectToLoad = new MyObject(cookieString)`.

Example

```
public class MyObject(){

    private String username;
    private int rank;
    private OtherObject otherObject;

    //Constructors,getters,setters,rest of class
    //...

    public MyObject(String s){
         this();
         //Trim class delimiter (  )
         String trimedStr = s.replaceAll("\(\\$", "").replaceAll("^\)\\", "");

         //parse string
         String[] components = trimedStr.split(",");
         this.username = components[0];
         this.rank     = Integer.valueOf(components[1]);
         //Otherobject should be constructed similar
         this.otherobject = new OtherObject(components[2]);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "("+username+","+rank+","+otherObject.toString()+")";
    }
 }
```

I used `"(",")"` to separate an object, but it is not necessary. If OtherObject contained 2 string values it would look like this:

```
(radu, 964 , ( string1 , string2 ) )
```

But if you do not have other objects, you can skip the `"(",")"` or simply store as just one list

```
(radu, 964 , string1 , string2 )
```

and have  `this.otherobject = new OtherObject(components[2],components[3]);`

Use [`JSON` format and `Jackson`](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) to not have to build the string format yourself (and modify it everytime your change the object class definition)

Comment: Which part? Spring? Plain String? JSON?

Comment: Plain String ! Two sides object to string and string to object thanks

Comment: I gave you a very general example. Please let me know if there are things which are unclear.

Comment: i got this "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )" about ("\(\\$", "")